# Can't resolve Google pagespeed "Enable compression" point using Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, pagespeed

Site in question is http://burghleys.com/

Having trouble trying to improve the Google pagespeed score and says I need to enable compression with a 70% improvement on the JS file for example but I can't make the same improvement at all!

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fburghleys.com%2F

I have GZIP enabled and use the apache mod_deflate to do so, tested as per http://checkgzipcompression.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fburghleys.com%2F

I use yii2 https://github.com/rmrevin/yii2-minify-view plugin to compress my files which generally works really well.

I use the HTML5 boiler plate htaccess file.

I tried manually compressing the JS file but can only reach 25%. CSS is even less yet states i can save 80%.

Any thoughts?

ps. I'm working on the other issues too, wanna get that 99 score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do have GZIP enabled for some items but if you follow the link to your js you will see that this resource is not being zipped up.

http://checkgzipcompression.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fburghleys.com%2Fminify%2Fb329b2d2ce53b5c6be05decfe5e5d723527a666e.js

Add the following line to your `.htaccess`

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/xml application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/javascript appliction/x-javascript
```

Comment: Ah found that the HTML5 boiler plate htaccess file checks for the mod "mod_filter.c" which I thought was installed but clearly not. The boiler plate already has that line in. Cheers!